# Should a table be split if only a particular column gets updates?

Tags: mysql, innodb, update, physical-design

I have a table in my MySQL 5.7 database, which has 9 columns. One column is an `AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, where as the other 6 contain some data, which isn't going to be updated in a year. Now, the last 2 columns are of type `JSON` and they are going to be updated frequently, multiple times in a second(could be 5 times a second, and as system scales could be much more than that).

My question is, should i split my table into 2 tables, having a one to one relationship? So that all the non changing data goes in one table and the 2 columns which are to be updated frequently go to the other table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Will you be accessing (`SELECTing`) *only* the 'static' data frequently?  With complex `WHERE` clauses?  If so, "vertical partitioning" is beneficial.  It would keep the `SELECTs` from interfering with the `UPDATEs`.

Will the `JSON` columns be large, and the 'static' columns be relatively small?  If so, that adds to the argument for vertical partitioning.

When you are ready to update a JSON field, do you have the `PRIMARY KEY` in hand?  Searching around for which row to change may interfere with other `UPDATEs`.

Sorry there is no straightforward answer; "your mileage may vary".

**Rephrasing**

(This discussion applies to any InnoDB table with "big" fields -- `TEXT`/`BLOB`/etc.)

If you *usually* access the big field (JSON, in your case) --> 1 table
If you *often* don't look at the big field --> 2 tables
If you *usually* do a "point query" (ie, you have the id of the row and don't need to search for it) --> 1 table
If you *often* check lots of rows to find the one (or few) to fetch/update --> 2 tables
But... If *most* rows are bigger than 8KB (and you are using InnoDB), then, because of the way 'large' columns are stored off-block, there is not much advantage for 2 tables.

Comment: If you are almost always accessing the JSON, there is not much advantage in vertical partitioning.  (I assume this is InnoDB.)

Comment: Yes the engine is InnoDB. This is one of my concern, as by splitting I add join over head, while **may be** reducing the update cost.